# JQuery Animate not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following Javascript code:

```
  // Animate .gallery element to the correct left position.
                $("#gallery-images").animate({
                    left : "-500px"
                },1500);
```

Which is being applied to this HTML:

```
         <div id="gallery-images">

            <?php foreach($content1 as $img) : ?>
                <div class="gallery-image-holder">
                    <a class="gallery-image" href="<?php echo "/granados/images/".$img['url'];?>"> <img src="<?php echo "/granados/images/".$img['url'];?>" /></a>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>

        </div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#gallery-images{
    display: inline-block;
    width:37em;
    height:11em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 4em;
    float:left;
    margin-right: .5em;

}
```

Everything appears to work, at least when I inspect the code via Chrome. The `left: "-500px"` is being set, but the element doesn't move. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding position (`position:relative`)

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. that worked. Make an answer and I'll accept. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You have your class/id wrong you would have to have

```
$(".gallery-images").animate({
                left : "-500px"
},1500);
```

because it is a class that you are calling

also the class you are trying to call is "gallery-images" but the class that you made is "gallery-image"

```
$(".gallery-image").animate({
                left : "-500px"
},1500);
```

so just fix that type and you should be good to go :)